# hadoop mongodb connector read data but outputting as mysql data

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hadoop

is it possible to read mongodb data with hadoop connector but save output as mysql data table. So I want to read some data from mongodb collection by hadoop, processing it with hadoop and outputing it NOT already in mongodb but as MYSQL.

Comment: You asked the same question and received an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965427/is-it-possible-to-read-mongodb-data-process-it-with-hadoop-and-output-it-into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used like, fetching data from mongodb as input and store result in different mongodb address. For that one you need to specify like

MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(discussConf,"mongodb://ipaddress1/Database.Collection");
MongoConfigUtil.setOutputURI(discussConf,"mongodb://ipaddress2/Database.Collection");

for mongodb to mysql 
my suggestion is , you can write normal java code to insert whatever data you need to insert in mysql . that code may be in reduce or map function