# Is it possible to read MongoDB data, process it with Hadoop, and output it into a RDBS (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hadoop, sqoop

> ## Summary:
>
> Is it possible to:
>
> 1. Import data into Hadoop with the «MongoDB Connector for Hadoop».
> 2. Process it with Hadoop MapReduce.
> 3. Export it with Sqoop in a single transaction.

I am building a web application with MongoDB. While MongoDB work well for most of the work,  in some parts I need stronger transactional guarantees, for which I use a MySQL database.

My problem is that I want to read a big MongoDB collection for data analysis, but the size of the collection means that the analytic job would take too long to process. Unfortunately, MongoDB's built-in map-reduce framework would not work well for this job, so I would prefer to carry out the analysis with [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

I understand that it is possible read data from MongoDB into Hadoop by using the [«MongoDB Connector for Hadoop»](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop), which reads data from MongoDB, processes it with MapReduce in Hadoop, and finally outputs the results back into a MongoDB database.

The problem is that I want the output of the MapReduce to go into a MySQL database, rather than MongoDB, because the results must be merged with other MySQL tables.

For this purpose I know that Sqoop can export result of a Hadoop MapReduce into MySQL.

Ultimately, I want too read MongoDB data then process it with Hadoop and finally output the result into a MySQL database.

Is this possible? Which tools are available to do this?

Comment: your question could be made much clearer. I'm not sure at all what you're trying to do. I'll edit your question to reflect what I think you're trying to say, but your clarification would be helpful too.

Comment: I update my question for clarification

Comment: have a look at my updated answer, which should explain how you can do what you're asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** Set an an output formatter that writes to a RDBS in your Hadoop job:
>
> ```
>  job.setOutputFormatClass( DBOutputFormat.class );
> ```

Several things to note:

1. Exporting data from MongoDB to Hadoop using Sqoop is not possible. This is because Sqoop uses [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html) which provides a call-level API for *SQL-based database*, but MongoDB **is not an SQL-based database**. You can look at the [«MongoDB Connector for Hadoop»](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/) to do this job. The connector is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop). (Edit: as you point out in your update.)
2. Sqoop exports are not made in a single transaction by default. Instead, according to the [Sqoop docs](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal):

   > Since Sqoop breaks down export process into multiple transactions, it is possible that a failed export job may result in partial data being committed to the database. This can further lead to subsequent jobs failing due to insert collisions in some cases, or lead to duplicated data in others. You can overcome this problem by specifying a staging table via the `--staging-table` option which acts as an auxiliary table that is used to stage exported data. The staged data is finally moved to the destination table in a single transaction.
3. The «MongoDB Connector for Hadoop» does not seem to force the workflow you describe. According to the docs:

   > This connectivity takes the form of allowing both reading MongoDB data into Hadoop (for use in MapReduce jobs as well as other components of the Hadoop ecosystem), as well as writing the results of Hadoop jobs out to MongoDB.
4. Indeed, as far as I understand from the [«MongoDB Connector for Hadoop»: examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/examples/), it would be possible to specify a [`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBOutputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBOutputFormat.html) into your Hadoop MapReduce job to write the output to a MySQL database. Following the example from the connector repository:

   ```
   job.setMapperClass( TokenizerMapper.class );
   job.setCombinerClass( IntSumReducer.class );
   job.setReducerClass( IntSumReducer.class );
   job.setOutputKeyClass( Text.class );
   job.setOutputValueClass( IntWritable.class );
   job.setInputFormatClass( MongoInputFormat.class );
   /* Instead of:
    * job.setOutputFormatClass( MongoOutputFormat.class );
    * we use an OutputFormatClass that writes the job results 
    * to a MySQL database. Beware that the following OutputFormat 
    * will only write the *key* to the database, but the principle
    * remains the same for all output formatters
    */
   job.setOutputFormatClass( DBOutputFormat.class );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at Apache Pig (which runs on top of Hadoop's map-reduce). It will output to MySql (no need to use Scoop). I used it to do what you are describing. It is possible to do an "upsert" with Pig and MySql. You can use Pig's STORE command with piggyBank's DBStorage and MySql's INSERT DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoHadoop connector to read data from MongoDB and process it using Hadoop.

Link:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/hive/README.md

Using this connector you can use Pig and Hive to read data from Mongo db and process it using Hadoop.

Example of Mongo Hive table:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestMongoHiveTable
    ( 
    id STRING,
    Name STRING
    )
    STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id","Name":"Name"}')
    LOCATION '/tmp/test/TestMongoHiveTable/' 
    TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://{MONGO_DB_IP}/userDetails.json');
```

Once it is exported to hive table you can use Sqoop or Pig to export data to mysql.

Here is a flow.

Mongo DB -> Process data using Mongo DB hadoop connector (Pig) -> Store it to hive table/HDFS -> Export data to mysql using sqoop.